# Utilizar mesmo id de tabela pai em filha - Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, herança, annotation

Estou tendo problemas em configurar e tratar o uso de `ID` em classes pai/filho utilizando `Hibernate`. 
Consigo que tudo funcione corretamente quando o registro não existe na tabela pai (os registros são criados com `id` correto nas tabelas pai e filha), mas quando o registro existe na tabela pai e preciso inseri-lo somente na filha, um novo id é criado.
Preciso que os IDs permaneçam iguais em ambas as tabelas

**Classe pai**:

```
==========================
@Entity
@Table(name = "FUNDOS" , schema = "LIMITE")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Fundo implements Comparable<Fundo>, FundoInterface {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Integer id;   

======================
```

**Classe Filha:**

```
======================
@Entity
@Table(name = "BENCHMARKS" , schema = "LIMITE")
public class Benchmark extends Fundo {


    Benchmark() {
    }

    public Benchmark(Fundo fundo) {
        this.id = fundo.getId();
        this.nome = fundo.getNome();
        this.codigoX = fundo.getCodigoX();
        this.codigoY = fundo.getCodigoY();
    }

============
```

**Como tratar ?**

Já tentei utilizar engenharia reversa para saber que anotações o `Hibernate` geraria a partir das tabelas já criadas...

Comment: Já tentou usar @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn("ID") na Tabela Benchmark?

Comment: Sim... já consultei manuais e todos os tutoriais disponíveis. Usei o @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn e não funcionou ..